# objectId in Parse is null, although there is no ParseException while saving object to Parse cloud

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, null, objectid

I am trying to save an object to Parse cloud and getting its objectId if it was successfully saved. I am printing the Exceptions in the logs if there is any. After clicking the save button, there is no ParseException shown in the logs but the objectId returned is always null.

this is my subclass:

```
@ParseClassName("PetOwner")
```

public class PetOwner extends ParseObject {

```
public PetOwner(){ super(); }

public String getOwnerId(){
   return getString("objectId");
}

public String getOwnerName(){
    return getString("name");
}

public ParseGeoPoint getLocation(){
    return getParseGeoPoint("location");
}

public String getPhoneNumber(){
    return getString("phoneNumber");
}

public Number getRadius(){
    return getNumber("searchRadius");
}

public Installation getInstallation(){
    return (Installation) getParseObject("installation");
}

public String getBackupEmail(){
    return getString("backupemail");
}

public String getEmail(){
    return getString("email");
}

public Date createdAt(){
    return getDate("createdAt");
}

public Date updatedAt(){
    return getDate("updatedAt");
}

public void setOwnerName(String name){ put("name", name); }

public void setPhoneNumber(String phone){ put("phoneNumber", phone); }

public void setEmail(String email){ put("email", email); }

public static ParseQuery<PetOwner> getQuery(){
    return ParseQuery.getQuery(PetOwner.class);
}
```

}

This is the code I am writing to save the object to the cloud after getting the values of the name, phone number and email fields entered by the users in EditText view.

```
 FloatingActionButton saveProfile = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.save_button);
saveProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (nameChanged && checkPhoneNumber() && checkEmail()) {
                final PetOwner petOwner = new PetOwner();
                petOwner.setOwnerName(userName.getText().toString());
                petOwner.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber.getText().toString());
                petOwner.setEmail(email.getText().toString());

                petOwner.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "after saveinbackground is done");
                        Log.d(TAG, petOwner.getOwnerId() + " is the saved object id");
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "saveinbackground NOT done");
                        Log.e(TAG, "exception", e);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The logs show this:

```
04-09 19:33:50.385 31818-31818/us.furalert.Furalert D/PetOwnerDetails: after saveinbackground is done 
04-09 19:33:50.385 31818-31818/us.furalert.Furalert D/PetOwnerDetails: null is the saved object id
```

I am not able to make out what is wrong with my code. Why is the objectId null?

Please help!

Comment: What if you replace getString("objectId") with getObjectId() as ParseObjects has a built-in method to retrieve objectId

Comment: @cYrixmorten thanks a lot!!! finally its working!

Comment: Nice :-) no problem. I just added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace getString("objectId") with getObjectId() as ParseObjects has a built-in method to retrieve the objectId